# Why does nargout return -1? And how to get the correct number of function outputs in that case?

Tags: matlab, function-handle

Why does [`nargout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) return -1 in this case?

```matlab
function test

fun=@(a)helper_fun(a,2);

[x,y]=fun(1);
x,  % 1
y,  % 2
nargout(fun),   % -1

end

function [c,d] = helper_fun(a,b)

c=a;
d=b;

end
```

Is there an alternative to extract the correct number of output variables of `fun`?

I was hoping to impose a syntax check in a function that takes `function_handle` as an optional variable and this artifact forced me to either change how my function must look or not check number of outputs.

Comment: What would you do with this information? First of all, the number of output arguments often depends on context. In general, even a function such as `helper_fun` could be called with one output argument only. Some functions *change* their behavior depending on the number of output arguments. Some functions *change* the number of output arguments depending on its input. All of this is possible, and so there is not a single answer for `nargout`.

Comment: Second, function handles are usually used as input to functions that specify how that function handle will be called. If the function expects two output arguments, you must pass a handle that produces two output arguments.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: On your second point, as in, if I simply call the function without checking `nargout` first with 2 outputs, it will prompt an error that reports incorrect number of outputs? That'll serve my purpose of syntax check actually --- to induce a prompt if I end up using the same module in different ways in the future. I'm just not sure if a call of `[a,b]=func(x)` can sometimes go through without error even if `func` has 3 outputs without `varargout`.

Comment: Yes, if `func` "has 3 outputs", then `[a,b]=func()` ignores the 3rd output. But again, "has" is the wrong term. "Can return up to 3 outputs" might be better wording. But also, I can define `function [a,b,c,d]=myfunction(n)`, and if `n==1`, return only one output, leaving the other ones unassigned. If I call `[a,b]=myfunction(1)`, it will produce an error message. But if I call `a=myfunction(2)`, then the output `b` is just ignored. MATLAB really does not treat inputs and outputs like C, it is all very flexible and hard to predict.

Comment: Another example: [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) calls a function handle and times how long it takes. This function has a 2nd input argument where you can specify with how many outputs the function handle should be called. Because the function could do something different depending on the number of outputs, and there is no way to know from the handle how many outputs there should be.

Comment: I'll need to keep that in mind in the future. I am afraid of a case such as having written a module intended to use an input of the form `[a,b]=fun(c)` but it ends up taking an input of the form `[x,y,z]=func(d)` when another module written in the future calls it. Yet the overall program runs nonetheless until very far down the line some difference between `a` and `x` triggers an error somewhere but the source of that error will be much harder to track. For now, I'll settled with checking syntax with a named function

Comment: If you want to allow two different types of functions as input, add another argument that distinguishes which type of function was given. You could even disguise that using the name-value pair syntax: `function(data,'twoargfun',fcn)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html#bvj45zv-3): `nargout` returns a negative value to mark the position of [`varargout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) in the function declaration. As an example, for a function declared as

```
[y, varargout] = example_fun(x)
```

`nargout` will give `-2`, meaning that the second "output" is actually `varargout`, which represents a comma-separated list that can contain any number of outputs.

`nargout` gives `-1` for anonymous functions because they can return any number of outputs. That is, their signature is equivalent to

```
varargout = example_fun(x)
```

How can an anonymous function return more than one output? As indicated [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/495945-multiple-outputs-from-anonymous-function#comment_776649), by delegating the actual work to another function that can. For example:

```
>> f = @(x) find(x);
>> [a, b, c] = f([0 0 10; 20 0 0])
a =
     2
     1
b =
     1
     3
c =
    20
    10
>> nargout(f)
ans =
    -1
```

Compare this to

```
>> f = @find;
>> nargout(f)
ans =
     3
```

The result is now `3` because `find` is defined with (at most) `3` outputs.

Comment: In other words, the signature of all anonymous functions is one that has `varargout` and there is no way around that? (In my application, it was convenient to have the `function_handle` refer to a named function directly because either way the underlying function I was hoping to pass along was a nested function. And so, passing variables using the anonymous function syntax confers no particular benefit.) In general though, it seems to make quite a difference being able to pass an underlying function and *some* of its inputs while being able to check function syntax.

Comment: Yes, I think that's necessarily the signature for anonymous functions. So it loses the information of what signature the inner function actually has. But note that it works with handles to named functions (as in my last example); in case that helps. Is there a way around that? Perhaps so. But it's going to be tricky

Comment: I see. Thanks. I can't really think of how to work around it with try/catch despite of the hint :(

Comment: It would involve calling the function with an increasing number of inputs until it issues an error (which is caught). But that method requires knowing the number and type of inputs to use; and calling the function may be slow

Comment: Yeah, you could do it the other way around as well, call it with fewer arguments until if doesn't produce an error. But then you're still running the function body over and over again, as the error is thrown when the function returns.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll keep the approach in mind. And yes, having to run the function in order to test whether an alternative syntax is viable and thus reject would be undesirable. Especially when waiting for return from remote server is involved.

Comment: (That said. The try/catch approach seems generalizable and can be applied if a small and locally run function is involved. Good to keep in mind for me.)